# Java String externalization key missing

Tags: java, string, configuration, resources, configuration-files

I used the Eclipse string externalisation wizard to extract strings which are then stored in  a configuration file. 
Although when I run it I keep getting an NPE whenever a resource or a System.getProperty() is called.

I can't seem to find documentation on this, is there a reason for this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find your externalized through `System.getProperty()`.

From the docs of `System.getProperty()`:

> *Gets the system property indicated by the specified key.*

When I run the *String externalization wizzard* I get a class called `Messages` on which I can call a `.getString` method like this:

```
Messages.getString("Test.STR0")
```